# Problems with "get" overriding when class created in Kotlin

Tags: class, kotlin, get

I studying kotlin and faced problem with overriding get when class created.
Here is code snippet:

```
class Person(name: String){
   var name = name
       get() = if (name.length < 2) "Default" else name
}

println(Person("John").name)
```

This code throws StackOveerflowError and I can't understand why. I thought, that I misunderstood use of if-else, but I checked and it seems  that all is correct

Comment: The keyword to access the backing field is `field` not the name of variable. If you use name of variable it will point to the getter again, which will go into infinite recursion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you dive into infinite recursion inside your getter, i.e

```
get() = if (name.length < 2) "Default" else name
         //   ^ here by calling 'name' you call its getter again, so getter will call itself infinitely
```

If you want to access value of the field inside of the getter use `field` identifier:

```
get() = if (field.length < 2) "Default" else field
```

[More info on official website](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html)